# Rundeck GA version Compatibility

Tags: rundeck

Currently I am using Rundeck 3.0.23-20190619.

Whether Rundeck 3.0.23-20190619 is stable version?

From the https://bintray.com/rundeck/rundeck-rpm/rundeck able to see the Rundeck 3.0.23-20190619 is not yet published as GA.

2.11.14-1.70.GA is the latest GA version with build date 2019-09-13T03:37:04.000Z.

Will the application developed with 3.0.23-20190619 compatible with 2.11.14-1.70.GA?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the latest stable release is 3.1.2, you can check the latest version in the changelog [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). The "GA" notation is not used anymore. In some cases, you can see some updates of 2.11 / 3.0 branches focused on backports, not for new features, etc.

Your projects and jobs are compatible using 2.11, 3.0 and 3.1 branches.

Comment: If I am not wrong. `3.0.1` to `3.0.26` are backports versions. Also `2.11.0-1.51.GA` to `2.11.11-1.63.GA` are backports versions.